# CakePHP 2.3. - redirect 301 not working

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I'm using Cakephp 2.3. and I'd like to redirect old pages to new pages with HTTP 301 status. Now my URLs look like http://www.example.com/profile/john and http://www.example.com/profile/john/shop

I'd like URLs to look like http://www.example.com/user/john and http://www.example.com/user/john/shop respectively

My routes.php

```
Router::connect(
    '/profile/:profile_name', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile', 
        'action' => 'index',
    ),
    array (
        'pass' => array('profile_name')
    )
);

Router::connect(
    '/profile/:profile_name/shop',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'shop'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('profile_name')
    )
);
```

My redirect is :

```
  Router::redirect(
    '/user/:profile_name',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'index',
    ),
    array (
        'persistent' => true,
        'status' => 301
    )
);

  Router::redirect(
    '/user/:profile_name/shop',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'shop',
    ),
    array (
        'persistent' => true,
        'status' => 301
    )
);
```

But It doesn't work. 404 page is still showing up

I was trying to do it as it is described in tutorial but nothing works

Comment: isnt your controller called `ProfilesController`?

Comment: Yes, it should be called Profiles - convention. Could it be the problem?

Comment: That could be the problem, you can try it by changing `'controller' => 'profile'` to `'controller' => 'profiles'`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because there is ',' more.

```
Router::connect('/profile/:profile_name', array('controller' => 'profile','action' => 'index') , array ('pass' => array('profile_name')));

Router::connect('/profile/:profile_name/shop', array('controller' => 'profile','action' => 'shop' ), array('pass' => array('profile_name')));
```

the same here:

```
  Router::redirect(
    '/user/:profile_name',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array (
        'persistent' => true,
        'status' => 301
    )
);

  Router::redirect(
    '/user/:profile_name/shop',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'shop'
    ),
    array (
        'persistent' => true,
        'status' => 301
    )
);
```

Comment: I don't get it, sorry, could you pls explain it more?

Comment: ok, there is a comma that you dont need after of your 'action' => 'index' ,  <--here, maybe I thing that is the problem, but in this case maybe not or this:    Router::connect('/profile/:profile_name/shop', array('controller' => 'profile','action' => 'index' , array('pass' => array('profile_name'))));